# Removing special characters from a text file

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

My input.txt is as below

```
    \n\n            \n        \n\n    \n\n\r\n\r\n    \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n        \r\n        \r\n    \r\n\r\n﻿\r\n    \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n        \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n        hello boys\r\n        boys\r\n    boys\r\n\r\n         Download PDF\r\n        PDF\r\n    X\r\n    Close Window\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n    
This boys text has undergone conversion so that it is mobile and web-friendly. This may have created formatting or alignment issues. Please refer to the PDF copy for a print-friendly version.
\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n    \r\n        
BOYS CLUB AUSTRALIA
\r\n
26 July 2019
\r\n
hello boys
\r\n
\r\nhello boys
\r\n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\r\n
Introduction
\r\n\r\n    
1. \r\n    
This letter to let you know that your application has been successful with our school
\r\n
```

I am trying to remove unnecessary patterns like "\n\n", "\r\r", "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"
While parsing, I want to remove all the special patterns and want to have only text and numbers.

I have tried as below.

```
with open (data, "r", encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        line.rstrip()
        line = re.sub(r'\r\n', '', line)
            with open("out.txt", "a",  encoding='utf-8') as output:
                output.write(line)
```

But even '\r\n' is not getting removed in output file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `replace()` method to to replace the `\r\n` substrings with an empty string.

```
with open(data, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
    with open('out.txt', 'a',  encoding='utf-8') as output:
        for line in myfile:
            output.write(line.replace('\r\n', '').rstrip())
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with replace() method also. Still the output file has "\r\n "

Comment: "\\r\\n"   resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To remove special characters, such as newline characters (\n), from a text file in Python, you can use the replace() method of the str class. This method allows you to replace a specific character or string of characters with another character or string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace but also `str.isprintable` to filter out not printable characters:

```py
input_file = 'input.txt'
output_file = 'output.txt'

with open (input_file, "r", encoding='utf-8') as infile:
    with open(output_file, "w", encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(
                ''.join(filter(str.isprintable, line.replace('\\n', '').replace('\\r', '')))
                + '\n'
            )
```

So, the output is:

```
                                                                        hello boys        boys    boys         Download PDF        PDF    X    Close Window    
This boys text has undergone conversion so that it is mobile and web-friendly. This may have created formatting or alignment issues. Please refer to the PDF copy for a print-friendly version.
            
BOYS CLUB AUSTRALIA

26 July 2019

hello boys

hello boys

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Introduction
    
1.     
This letter to let you know that your application has been successful with our school
```